# How to extract specific value from string in java

Tags: java, string

How i can extract any value from the table below, for example code_challenge as i count manage it use Matcher and pattern what could be other solutions

```
  String text = "
client_id: '2ff43eff-acc2-4f8e-90cf-75fae647b2fw'
code_challenge: 'sNuXRRk_sdfd3YhPBKiHXFA'
code_challenge_method: 'S2dd56'
response_mode: 'query'
response_type: 'code'
scope: 'openid'
state: 'b4sdsd6848867d566b734f8'
"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String text = "client_id: '2ff43eff-acc2-4f8e-90cf-75fae647b2fw'\n" +
        "                code_challenge: 'sNuXRRk_sdfd3YhPBKiHXFA'\n" +
        "        code_challenge_method: 'S2dd56'\n" +
        "        response_mode: 'query'\n" +
        "        response_type: 'code'\n" +
        "        scope: 'openid'\n" +
        "        state: 'b4sdsd6848867d566b734f8'";

int varNameIndex = text.indexOf("code_challenge");
int valueStartIndex = text.indexOf("'", varNameIndex) + 1;
int valueEndIndex = text.indexOf("'", valueStartIndex);
String value = text.substring(valueStartIndex, valueEndIndex);

System.out.println(value);
```